# how to use pip install a package if there are two same version of python on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have two same versions of python on windows. Both are 3.6.4. I installed one of them, and the other one comes with Anaconda.

My question is how do I use pip to install a package for one of them? It looks like  the common method will not work since the two python versions are the same.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'common method'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Answer (score 1):

`pip` points to only one installation because `pip` is a script from one `python`.

If you have one Python in your `PATH`, then it's that python and that `pip` that will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualenv, conda environment or pipenv, it will help with managing packages for different projects.